# Calculate the amount of the cost of tickets finalized per material divided by the total amount of the tickets finalized

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following need :

Calculate the ratio between the sum of the amounts of tickets with status finalized for each material and the sum of the total amounts of the tickets finalized.

My fact table is like below :

```
TicketID StatusID MaterialID CategoryID Amount  FKDATE
123      3        45         9          150     12/03/2021
124      5        50         4          569     11/03/2021
125      3        78         78         556     14/03/2021
126     -1        -1         -1         -1      12/03/2021
```

My dimension Status is like below :

```
 StatusID Status
 1        Open
 2        In Process
 3        Finalized
```

My dimension Material is like below :

```
MaterialID  MaterielLabel
1           Bikes
..          ..
```

I want to exclude the TicketID with MaterialID = -1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
AmountFinalizedByMaterial:= 
VAR AmountFinalizedByMaterialGroup =
CALCULATE (
SUM(yourFactTable[Amount]),
Status[Status] = "Finalized" ,
yourFactTable[MaterialID] <> -1)

VAR TotalAmountFinalized =
CALCULATE (
SUM(yourFactTable[Amount]),
Status[Status] = "Finalized" ,
ALL(Material)
)
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        AmountFinalizedByMaterialGroup,
        TotalAmountFinalized
    )
```